# algorithm for building multi-class (versus binary) classifiers

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

i am a student and now i am doing research about text classification.
i have read several paper about that.
but i just found so many people using naive bayesian classifier.

```
i have 4 class to classify.
and i read that SVM can only classify thing into 2 class,..yes/no 1/0
```

is there any algorithm besides NBC algorithm for building classifiers to separate data into *more than* two classes?

Comment: check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification)

Answer (score 1):

most ML techniques are capable of building multi-class classifiers, for instance:

- **decision tree** (eg C4.5)
- **neural network** via softmax (aka multi-layer perceptron, or MLP)
- **LDA** (linear discriminant analysis)
- **Naive Bayes**

Support vector machines are also routinely used for multi-class classification (see this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) from the excellent *scikit-learn library*), using for instance, a "one-against-many" inductive approach. In other words, the data is trained on a *first* SVM to separate the data into Class I versus everything else. Then the "everything else" data is passed to a *second* SVM which separates the data into Class II versus everything else, and so on.

Comment: nice sir, i have read that method about one against many but not clear like your description,so is there any alternative (method name and not domain) besides NBC, SVM, or artificial neural network??

Comment: not sure what you mean by "method name and not domain", but in light of your comment above, i added two more techniques that routinely used to build multi-class classifiers and which are particularly suitable for text classification (i have used them for this purpose and indeed they are often recommended in ML textbooks for these use cases)